# Moto 360 Malfunctioning Gyroscope After Android 5.1 Update

Tags: android, wear-os

Since the Android 5.1 update (or not sure if this was always the case, but I don't suspect it was), the Moto 360 no longer reports useful gyroscope data. I've verified this abnormal behavior across three different Moto 360 devices.

Here is a link to a Google Spreadsheet that contains raw sensor data (capturing my arm flailing motion) for the Moto 360 on page 1, and then the sensor data for the G Watch R on page 2. Note that sensorType 0 is for gyroscope, and 1 is for accelerometer.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11154fiVCSro111apVkYSlz1s4VW8D5X82WZsNTTHnCE/edit?usp=sharing

As you can observe, the Moto 360 reports gyroscope data in 20 ms intervals, but the values reported do not change. Meanwhile on the GWR, sensor data reports in even increments between accelerometer and gyroscope, and the values continously change (as expected).

Have any Wear developers run into this issue as well, and has anyone found a potential solution?

Comment: wilde guess here. Fit was not working until today for (always counting zero steps), and all of a sudden is back to operation, maybe there's some Google Play Services rollout fixing stuff, and soon it should be back to normal.

Comment: @Hyunbin  I am having exactly the same issue you mentioned. Have you figured out a solution ? Thanks.

Comment: @Hyunbin I'm also having the same issue..  For a while it looked like it would only work after it detected some significant motion, but now it doesn't seem to work at all..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the gyro is not working anymore. I made a ticket and now got the confirmation from motorola support, in German:

> "Obwohl das Gyroskop nicht absichtlich abgeschaltet wurde im letzten
>   Update, scheint es doch dazu gekommen zu sein, dass es Funktion
>   beeinträchtigt wurde. Das Gyroskop war keine Funktion, die besonders
>   beworben wurde und alle Funktionen gehen auch ohne das Gyroskop. Daher
>   ist die Korrektur dieses Fehlers zwar auf unserer Liste, aber nicht
>   Priorität."

My translation:
They say Motorola switched off the gyro accidentaly on the last (Android) update. They did not explicity advertised the gyro, and all functions work with out gyro, so it has no priority to fix the issue.

Bad luck here.

Comment: Wtf? That's awful! Did they turn it back on on the 6.0 update?