# Did Android Wear 6.0 update change SensorManager?

Tags: java, android, accelerometer, wear-os, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have an app for Android Wear that uses the embedded accelerometer, and I'm registering the sensor listener like this:

```
mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
mSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

// ...

mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

Before the Marshmallow update, my app was receiving updates every `200ms` using `SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL`. After the update, this changed to every `40ms`.

That's way faster than before, and it happened right after the Android Wear update.

I'm using Motorola Moto 360 1st gen. Now running with Android 6.0.1 (It was 5.1 before)

Did something change on the `SensorManager` class? Why is it reading 5 times faster?

---

**EDIT:** Just saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31078293/moto-360-malfunctioning-gyroscope-after-android-5-1-update), and I wonder if it has something to do with it. Maybe motorola did change something on this 6.0 update.

Comment: I checked the source code for `SensorManager` and didn't see anything obvious...

Comment: That's odd. And I'm not even sure if that's really what changed. Maybe motorola changed something behind the scenes?

Comment: Perhaps I'm being dense, but why does it matter? Different devices have always had different sensor refresh rates, and our code needs to handle this. Why is this situation any different? Honest question.

Comment: It's not like this broke my app or something. I'm aware that different devices have different refresh rates, but that behavior was just weird. And there's something else to consider. If I read from the accelerometer using a faster rate, I'll drain the battery a bit faster, right?